# How to refresh ListView in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, listactivity

I know you can call notifyDataSetChanged();  How would you do that in this context -- is it even possible?

```
        ListView listView = getListView();
        listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Items.this, R.layout.list, items));
```

Edit:  I have changed to one of the suggestions below.  Here is what I am doing:

```
    protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Items.this, R.layout.list, items);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

Here I am refreshing inside an AsyncTask method.  This is being called inside a Dialog with a Submit button on top of a ListLiew.  The Dialog inserts new data into a database and I want the list refreshed where to reflect this.    I have tried this code above AND inside the onClick for the Button in the Dialog.  Right before dialog dismissed.

Comment: do you update your items list with the new inserted elements and then try to notify the adapter?

Comment: Yes, I call an HttpPost, run a Script to insert data into a database via PHP.  Then back in Java I am attempting to refresh listview after that is done.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the `ArrayAdapter` by itself:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Items.this, R.layout.list, items);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

...then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on that:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Note that you only need to call this method if the data actually changes; given this, you probably need to have it stored as a member variable in the class so it can be accessed later.

Comment: I do remember that your method was the way I was trying.  However, I have updated my quesiton with more code and it is still not working.

Comment: Firstly: Try `getListView().setAdapter(...);`. Next, are you sure the item list is updated? Verify this with `items.length`. After creating a new `ArrayAdapter` and calling `setAdapter` on it, `notifyDataSetChanged` should not even be needed.

Comment: I am not sure if it updated.  All I am doing is adding a new row into the database that the ListView pulls from.  Then I want to refresh the list so it pulls once again form the same (MySql) table.

Comment: Then, once the row is added to the database, check if `items.length` has increased. If it hasn't, your data isn't being pulled, so it won't add anything to the `ListView`.

Comment: I know this is a late question, I'm certain I am not pulling the data after it has been added.  So my question is, how do I that?  I though that is what the NotifyDataSetChanged was doing.

Comment: I would add the row to the database and also to the adapter at the same time. That way you don't have to worry about pulling all that data when you already know what's been added. You could pull the data anyway, but that can just update the data you already have, if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to call notifyDataSetChanged() on your ArrayAdapter, since ArrayAdapter extends BaseAdapter

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html

In your example you'd do something like this, taking that you meant to call listView.setListAdapter()

```
(ArrayAdapter)listView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you shouldn't be setting the adapter in your `AsyncTask`.  Generally it is a good idea to do that in `onCreate()` because otherwise you are setting it each time `AsyncTask` is called.  If you make your adapter a member variable, then you should be able to call `<adapter>.notifyDataSetChanged()` from within the `AsyncTask`.

Comment: Hey thanks for the feedback.  It is actually a member variable.  I will get rid of the setting code and just leave the notify.  Tough I believe I have already tried this.